# Timer in asp.net works perfectly in localhost but not online

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer, updatepanel

Timer in asp.net works when I run the application in localhost and when I upload and check online timer just don't work.

I have a condition when user click on "Request Item" button, in a label a message should show as "Submitted successfully" else "Some Error Message". So, What I did was, I created an update panel and inside that I placed a submit button with 2 labels one for successful message and another for error message. And a timer control, which I've setted up for 2 seconds in order to show message for just 2 seconds and hide them.

Here is my sorce code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">                                           

  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Request Item" Width="128px" OnClick="btnAdd_Click1" Height="38px" />
    <asp:Label ID="lblSuccess" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#00CC00"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="lblErrorMessage" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                                                    <br />
    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick1" Enabled="False">
                                                    </asp:Timer>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Below is the code where timer control is triggered under "Request Item" button.

```
lblSuccess.Visible = true;
lblSuccess.Text = "Records Successfully Saved!";
Timer1.Enabled = true;
```

Below is the code under timer tick event.

```
protected void Timer1_Tick1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtCount.Text = txtCount.Text + 1;

        if (txtCount.Text == "11")        //Here "11" is counted as each timer tick. 1 for 1 timer tick
        {
            lblSuccess.Visible = false;
            lblErrorMessage.Visible = false;
            Timer1.Enabled = false;
            txtCount.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: This would rather be a job for a JavaScript timer, not a server-side timer.

Comment: if you are using ToolScriptManager try to add attribute CombineScript="false" in that and try..once i got this error i got this solution and it worked..

Comment: Yes I'm using ajax script for calender and update panel

Comment: @jilu did u tried my suggestion..

Comment: @Jilu Glad it helped..will put it as answer mark it solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using `ToolScriptManager` try to add attribute `CombineScript="false"` in that and try..