# Timer in asp.net works perfectly in localhost but not from outside

Tags: asp.net, ajax, timer, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

Timer in asp.net works when I run the application in localhost and when I upload and check online timer just don't work.

I copied the question from this topic because it's the same one, but the solution doesn't work anymore because "ToolScriptManager" was removed from Ajax libraries.

[Timer in asp.net works perfectly in localhost but not online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30230003/timer-in-asp-net-works-perfectly-in-localhost-but-not-online)

So what should I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think putting the Timer into UpdatePanel solved it.